# Lookup the latest value from different query into a new column

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I'm learning PowerQuery and PowerBI by making a small stock market app.

Excel File - [Here](https://filetransfer.io/data-package/ZcsXt3mw#link)

I'm facing the following issue -

I've the following Queries -

[image]

`StockHistoricData` has the last year's data of all the stocks I want to track **on a day-on-day basis**.

`Tradebook` has all the stocks that I've traded (buy/sell) (which may not be all present in `StockHistoricData`)

I want to make a custom column in `Tradebook` with the name `CurrentPrice` that fetches the latest price(`StockHistoricData[ltp]`  based on `StockHistoricPrice[Date]`.

For eg. if `Tradebook` has `Tradebook[Symbol]` as **INFY** then I want to get the `StockHistoricData[ltp]` for `12-Jan-2024`.

**I tried it using List.PositionOf but it keeps on connecting to the website I've fetched the data from rather than using the already fetched data. Is there a way to stop this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Power Query will always stream data from the source - that is just the way it works. If query B depends on query A then whenever you refresh query B, data will be restreamed for query A too. In your case, if query A is a website and you want to avoid restreaming that data, you can load the result of query A to an Excel table and save it. Then update query B to get data from the now static query A Excel file.

Ben Gribaudo has a good article on how this works: https://bengribaudo.com/blog/2023/03/03/7292/lazy-streamed-immutable-try-building-a-table#more-7292

Relevant quote:

> In M, a table isn’t stored in memory as a fully materialized set of
> row and column values. Rather, a table is represented as a
> programmatic construct that contains a handle which can be used to
> request that the promised rows be produced on demand, one at a time
> (the technical term for this behavior is streaming). The expressions
> defining those rows and columns will then be evaluated only if their
> values are actually needed (lazy evaluation).

Comment: Thanks David! Thats a great article indeed. Can you please let me know how will I go about find the `ltp` price part if I go on to make it as a table?

Comment: Hey David! I've solved the above issue. I'm duplicating the `StockHistoricData` query, Grouping on Stocks and Max(Date). Then using List.PositionOf to get the `ltp` price from `StockHistoricData` to get the price. But as you said it's refreshing every time. Hence, it's slow. Can you review it and see if there's a better way to do it? https://filetransfer.io/data-package/7cbZNx90#link

Comment: Do you still need me to look at something or have  you solved it?

Comment: You need to create a separate Excel file with the StockHistoricData  query in there and then load that to an Excel table. Close that file and then update your original file's query to point to the new Excel workbook you created and get the data from there.

Comment: No, there's no need to look into it. Your fix seems good to me I'll implement it and let you know if I need some further help. Thank you for all the help, David! Appreciate it.

Comment: Hey Davide! I just used `Table.Buffer` to load the table to memory and now the sequential calls to the referenced table are almost instant. But I feel if the table grows large this is probably not an optimal way.

Comment: Yes, Table.Buffer is useful but beware of memory issues if you buffer too much